# Insert Newline and Carriage-Return into Swift String

Tags: xcode, swift, arduino

I'm writing an OS X app that interacts with an Arduino UNO via serial connection. It currently has no problem reading strings from the UNO but I can't manage to send it the proper Newline and Carriage-Return characters on outgoing strings.

The code responsible for sending the string is as follows:

```
    @IBAction func SendCommand(sender: AnyObject) {
    let data = self.sendTextField.stringValue.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    self.serialPort?.sendData(data)
}
```

For the moment I have attempting to manually insert '\r\n' at the end of messages when the program is running. Should this not be equivalent to what the Arduino IDE would do programatically in it's own serial monitor? However my app isn't interpreting these commands as Newline of Carriage-Return characters. Is it only possible programatically and if so how?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Code please showing adding /r/n and also hex dumps. Breakup the compound statement into several simple statements, it makes debugging easier, there is nothing to gain by mashing all the method calls together.

Comment: Well for the moment I was simply entering \r\n after I had entered a command in my program (Command: This is a command\r\n) just to verify that it would work but for some reason that didn't work. I imagine it's that the escape characters are only recognized within the program, is this correct?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well after all it looks like the escape characters weren't being recognized when I included them with the command so I've fixed it in the program itself. Thank you for your time!

```
   @IBAction func SendCommand(sender: AnyObject) {
    var test = (self.sendTextField.stringValue) + "\r\n"
    let data = test.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    self.serialPort?.sendData(data)
}
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks